# Bash script - determine vendor and install system (apt-get, yum etc)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, installation

I'm writing a shell script for use on various linux platforms. Part of the script installs a couple of packages. How can I determine the linux vendor and default system install mechanism, for example Debian/Ubuntu has apt-get/apt, Fedora has yum and so on...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can find the linux distro using `/etc/lsb-release` and `/etc/os-release`. Not sure if there is a way to find the package management system. You can perhaps have a switch case against known distros.

Comment: @Vivek thanks, I hadn't thought of that, though hopefully there's an existing method/command for finding out the default installer.

Comment: take a look at [this on unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46086/42721)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't really need to check for vendor as they *may* decide to change packaging system (unlikely but conceptually, you would have to ensure that for each distro you test for, you try the right package manager command). All you have to do is test for the installation itself:

```
  YUM_CMD=$(which yum)
  APT_GET_CMD=$(which apt-get)
  OTHER_CMD=$(which <other installer>)
```

and then possibly sort them in your preference order:

```
 if [[ ! -z $YUM_CMD ]]; then
    yum install $YUM_PACKAGE_NAME
 elif [[ ! -z $APT_GET_CMD ]]; then
    apt-get $DEB_PACKAGE_NAME
 elif [[ ! -z $OTHER_CMD ]]; then
    $OTHER_CMD <proper arguments>
 else
    echo "error can't install package $PACKAGE"
    exit 1;
 fi
```

you can take a look at how gentoo (or framework similar to yocto or openembedded) provide approach to even get the source code (with wget) and build from scratch if you want a failsafe script.

Comment: Note it is possible to have (to some extent with ported etc version) to have `apt-get` on RPM systems, `yum` on DEB systems.

Comment: Is there difference if I check for `apt-get` or `apt`? or there are scenarios where I should check for both, like: `APT_GET_CMD=$(which apt-get)` and `APT_CMD=$(which apt)` ?

Comment: At the time I provided that answer, there was only apt-get. As of today, as far as I can tell, if apt is available, so is apt-get so testing for apt-get is the most general. Doesn't hurt to test for both though.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

OS=$(uname -s | tr A-Z a-z)

case $OS in
  linux)
    source /etc/os-release
    case $ID in
      debian|ubuntu|mint)
        apt update
        ;;

      fedora|rhel|centos)
        yum update
        ;;

      *)
        echo -n "unsupported linux distro"
        ;;
    esac
  ;;

  darwin)
    brew update
  ;;

  *)
    echo -n "unsupported OS"
    ;;
esac
```